# How to save Files and Folder in a general List?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sharepoint

I have initialized a general list and I want to save all Files and Folders from Sharepoint.

```
List<object> filesAndFolders = new List<object>();
```

I have loaded all files and folders from SharePoint and added them to the list and now I want to access FieldValues, but when I try to iterate through the list I can't access the file or folder because is being saved as an object{Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.File} or Folder.

```
foreach(var item in filesAndFolders){
      //getFiledValues here
      item.ListItemAllFields.FiledValues .. 
}
```

I have an error saying that item.ListItemAllFields.FiledValues doesn't exist. How can I solve this and be able to save Files and Folders in one List?
Thank you!

Comment: The class `object` doesn't have the Property `ListItemAllFields` so the compiler will complain. In your generic list you could store other types of objects as well that don't have that property so the compiler is protecting you from errors. To access that property you'll need to convert the entry to theproper type , e.g. `var fileItem = item as Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.File;` then use fileItem. If item wasn't really of that type, then fileItem will be null and you'll get an error at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the type of object at run-time like this:

```
            List<object> filesAndFolders = new List<object>();
            foreach (var item in filesAndFolders)
            {
                if (item is Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.File)
                {
                    var fileItem = item as Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.File;
                    // do stuff with fileItem
                }
                else if (item is Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Folder)
                {
                    var folderItem = item as Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Folder;
                    // do stuff with folderItem
                }
                else
                {
                    // Oops, some other object type
                }
            }
```

Althogh I can't access @Fildor's fiddle due to company firewall, I believe he or she is suggesting one of the following more compact forms:

```
        foreach (var item in filesAndFolders)
            {
                if (item is Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.File fileItem)
                {
                    // do stuff with fileItem
                }
                else if (item is Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Folder folderItem)
                {
                    // do stuff with folderItem
                }
                else
                {
                    // Oops, some other object type
                }
            }
```

or this

```
foreach (var item in filesAndFolders)
            {
                switch (item)
                {
                    case File fileItem:
                        // do stuff with fileItem
                        break;
                    case Folder folderItem:
                        // do stuff with folderItem
                        break;
                    default:
                        // Oops, some other object type
                        break;
                }
            }
```

which became possible in c# version 7.0.

Comment: You can do both in one and in a switch : https://dotnetfiddle.net/rUmoEr

Comment: @Fildor, you're right, that's how I'd do it myself but sometimes separating the steps and using simpler constructions make it clearer for the OP. Why not post your suggestion as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ClientObject as a type in your list.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject;

List<ClientObject> filesAndFolders = new List<ClientObject>();

foreach(var item in filesAndFolders){
    //getFiledValues here
}
```

Comment: OP is using classes from `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client` Namespace. You could make composites, but not make them be based on a custom class.